# Writing R-thonic code in R

Tags: r, debugging, readability, code-readability

What were the design decisions that led to R having often more than one way of doing things, that have subtle difference? See, for a good example,

https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/

More more such issues are here, some which are justified, some which are not http://r4stats.com/articles/why-r-is-hard-to-learn/

From a software engineering perspective, having such choices in a language screams for having subtle and hard-to-find bugs in your code (e.g. in Python the whole point of writing "pythonic" code, that avoids ambiguity and is easy to read and consistent in style). So there must be some major advantages of having that. What are they?